# Access denied to created spreadsheet google node API

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets

I'm using the google node API to generate a spreadsheet. The 3rd party library I use is the official one (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). Here is the code I use to generate the spreadsheet:

```
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

sheets.spreadsheets.create({
    auth: auth,
    resource: {
        properties:{
            title: "Google export"
        }
    }
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Added");
        res.send(response);
    }
});
```

It works fine and generate the sheet, when I display the response object, I get the link to the spreadsheet:

> spreadsheetUrl: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XS_QHxPUQcGqZGAzFHkHZV-RSKsv5IpJazcjVpLTYkk/edit"

But when I try to open it in the browser, I can't: `You need permission`.
The thing is if I click on the `Request access` button, I think it actually sends a request to the `client_email` from my credential (user@project-174309.iam.gserviceaccount.com), so it doesn't work. 
If I open the spreadsheet programmatically it works...

Does anyone know how to open the generated spreadsheet in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/804#issuecomment-327931203

Need to use Google Drive API to grant permissions for this file

Comment: help me alot after spending to much time finally this links work for me.